# Pass SQL column name as attribute of cursor.execute()

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I want to pass a column name as attribute of the function `cursor.execute()` with

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (?) VALUES (?)", (column, value))
```

Is that possible?

In the current form I receive the error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, assuming `column` is not user defined input.

```
cursor.execute(
    "INSERT INTO table ({column}) VALUES (?)".format(column=column),
    (value,)
)
```